# How do I keep the scanner class open to enter a new value for an instance

Tags: java

I have an assignment to create a Circle class which creates a circle using radius and then uses get to find the area, diameter, etc.

The next step in the assignment is to "Continuously use the Scanner object created at beginning to ask user to enter another value for radius." at first I tried to copy+paste the code to ask the user for radius and assign to a local variable like i did originally and I get the following error: "The assigned value is never used." Also the assignment says to change the value of the circle instance, not to make a new circle and assign that a different value.

I did some searches but am unsure how to proceed.

Code for my circle.java class:

```
public class Circle {

    // intialize variable radius
    private double radius;
    // create constant PI
    public final static double PI = 3.14159;

    // Circle constructtor
    public Circle(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }

    // setRadius method
    public void setRadius(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }

    // getRaduis method
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    // getArea method
    public double getArea() {
        double area = PI * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }

    // getDiameter method
    public double getDiameter() {
        double diameter = 2 * radius;
        return diameter;
    }

    // getCircumference method
    public double getCircumference() {
        double circumference = 2 * PI * radius;
        return circumference;
    }

}
```

And the code for my program circleTest:

```
package circle;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double circleRadius;
        double radius;

        // import scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ask user for raduis and store in a local variable
        System.out.print("What is the radius of the circle?");
        circleRadius = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Create a circle object called circle1
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(circleRadius);

        // display area using getArea method for circle1
        System.out.println("The area of the circle is " + circle1.getArea());

        // display diameter for circle1 using getDiameter method
        System.out.println("The diamter of a the circle is "
                + circle1.getDiameter());

        // display the circumference of circle1 using getCircumference
        System.out.println("The circumference of a circle is "
                + circle1.getCircumference());

        // ask user for radius and store in a local variable
        System.out.print("What is the radius of the circle?");
        circleRadius = keyboard.nextDouble();

    }
}
```

Comment: That's "not how quotes are supposed to be used".

Comment: my guess is to use a loop to continually ask for user input, create a new Circle object, and then output the results

Comment: oops i left something out, the assignment called to change the values of the original circle object, not create a new circle which was my first thought.

Comment: You have your `Circle` instance `circle1`. When you read new values from the `Scanner`, call the setters on `circle1` to change it internally.